# php apply filters is not working

Tags: php, woocommerce

I got a problem with my php code. I use woocommerce and have to apply a filter to the products on the cart-page with some information of the product. I've used apply_filters but can't get it to work.

Here is code from the woocommerce-file that works fine with item_weight but not area.

```
<p>Stk/m<sup>2</sup>:</p>
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_weight', $_product->get_weight()); ?>
<p>Test<sup>2</sup>:</p>
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_area_unit' $thepostid->get_area());?>
<span><?php echo($_area)?>M2<span>
```

And here is code from the other plugin that should work with the code above.

```
function wc_price_calculator_product_options_dimensions() {
global $thepostid;

woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => '_area', 'label' => __( 'Area', WC_Measurement_Price_Calculator::TEXT_DOMAIN ) . ' (' . get_option( 'woocommerce_area_unit' ) . ')', 'description' => __( 'Overrides the area calculated from the width/length dimensions for the Measurements Price Calculator.', WC_Measurement_Price_Calculator::TEXT_DOMAIN ) ) );
```

Hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just missing a comma?

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_area_unit', $thepostid->get_area());?>
```

... versus...

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_area_unit' $thepostid->get_area());?>
```